# GC in Workstation mode in ASP.NET app

Tags: asp.net, garbage-collection

I'm looking at dumps and I see

> mscorwks!WKS::GCHeap::GarbageCollectGeneration+0x1a9.

If I understand it is GC doing GarbageCollection in Workstation Mode? I see other threads are waiting on `mscorwks!WKS::GCHeap::WaitUntilGCComplete+0x34`.

Does that mean I run with workstation concurent=false mode of GC? I know that this server is one processor with one core. Should I change to concurent=true for ASP.NET App?

If I add another processor will GC automatically run in Server mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concurrent GC is meant for interactive (UI) applications. For server applications such as ASP.NET, non-concurrent GC should be preferred. As per [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhwwzef8.aspx), ASP.NET choose what is the best as per system config and you don't have alter this settings.

Go through [garbage collection documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx.aspx) on MSDN for more information. As to answer, your last part of question - generally, CLR Host can override configured GC mode value. As per [MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), ASP.NET will choose server GC for multi-processor machines. So yes, if you add one more processor, you should see your ASP.NET app using server mode GC.

On side note, probably reliable way to find out the GC mode is using [GCSettings.IsServerGC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.gcsettings.isservergc.aspx) property. Similarly, [GCSettings.LatencyMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384202.aspx) will tell you if its concurrent GC or not. For example, in workstation mode, *Interactive* value indicates concurrent GC.